# Why does importing a PSD from Creative Cloud libraries into After Effects return a tiny image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-after-effects, adobe-creative-cloud

I created an asset in Photoshop which is 1105x165, converted it into a smart object, and added it to my Creative Cloud libraries, so that I can access that asset in After Effects. This makes it so that if I update my Photoshop content, it will update the asset in After Effects, and it makes it so I can avoid rendering the asset to an intermediate format.

This is the asset in question:

> [image]

Here's a screenshot showing the size of the asset according to Creative Cloud Libraries:

[image]

However, when I drag this from Libraries into my composition, the resulting asset is *tiny*:

[image]

When I look in my project assets, the asset is showing up as a PNG and at an absolutely tiny scale:

[image]

For some reason, the input image is 1105x165, and the asset that is imported into my project is 248x37.

Two questions emerge:

1. **Why is it not seeing this as a Photoshop asset, and rather seeing it as a PNG?**
2. **Why is it scaling the source image down to be absolutely tiny?**

I believe the source item in my libraries is a smart object from Photoshop that I had created. Is there a different/better way to import a linked Photoshop asset that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Wow! Odd? So are After Effects and Photoshop all the same versions?

Comment: Yes, they are all up to date with the latest from Creative Cloud.